# Show posts for correct day with time zones

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I am setting up a system using PHP and MySQL in which users can add posts to specific days (all posts will be grouped by day).

So When a user goes to the main page, the user will see all of the posts for that day.

Now the problem - Time-zones:
What if I have 2 users, who are 3 hours apart.
User A will post at 12:00 AM, which will add the post to that specific day.
User B, who is in a different time zone, so for this user, it will still be the previous day, say 9:00 PM, will not see the post from user A since user B is still in the previous day in his time zone - this is fine.

Now, when user B gets to the next day (the same day as user A, meaning + 3 hours), he should see all of the posts for that day, but here is the problem:
For user B, user A's posts were added to the previous day, which means that user B will not see user A's post (when user A posted, it was 9:00 PM for user B on the previous day).

So the problem is with the time of the post, I'm not sure how to set this up, and I may be thinking about it all wrong - I actually have a feeling that I am missing something very basic in the logic.
I have searched for similar puzzles but did not really find anything that helped.

Any ideas and/or solutions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Store it all in UTC and ignore time-zones except when rendering times *for a particular user* with time-zone settings.

Comment: adding to the @tadman comment, it's usually a good practice to store time information in UTC and make the necessary calculations at  render time for the particular user because it keeps things a lot simpler when you have users from multiple timezones, alternatively you can always make the timezone of the server the 'true' timezone and render the same-page for everyone irrespective of timezones, but I think that's not your idea

Comment: *"User B, who is in a different time zone, so for this user, it will still be the previous day, say 9:00 PM, will not see the post from user A since user B is still in the previous day in his time zone - this is fine."* That's not fine.  When A posts and B views, B's "today" is relevant, not A's.  Store as UTC but query and display "days" relative to the viewer's local midnight expressed in UTC.  If you're 3 hours ahead of me, then what you did at 0200 on Friday, you actually did at 2300 on Thursday as far as I am concerned.  That it was "tomorrow" for you is usually irrelevant to me.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! So my thought is that when user B's time reaches 0200 on Friday, he will now see all the posts for Friday, but for user B, what user A posted would be recorded at 2300 Thursday, so user B would not see those posts because their dates would translate to Thursday and not to Friday. And just for more information, i have the post date and time as "posted 1 hour ago, posted 1 minute ago, posted 1 day ago, etc." - If user B would go to the site and were in fact to see user A's posts, wouldn't user B see on his end that the post was "posted yesterday"?